# Question on obtaining the "weak" formulation of the FEM.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, finite-element-method

The following is a part of the "line of thought" on how we obtain the "weak" formulation of the classical form of the one-dimensional problem for the Finite Element Method, but there is one small part I don't quite get.

> *"Supposing we have a given $f\in L_2(0,1)$, and we look for a "minimizing function", $u \in H^1_0(0,1)$ such that,
>   $$F(u)\le F(v),\,\forall v\in H^1_0(0,1),$$
>   where $F:H^1_0(0,1)\to\mathbb R$ is the energy functional:
>   $$F(v)=\frac12(v',v')-(f,v),$$
>   where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes the inner product function.
>   Now, assuming that some $u$ satisfies the first inequality, then given a function $v\in H^1_0(0,1)$ and $\epsilon\in\mathbb R$, then $u+\epsilon v\in H^1_0(0,1)$, so,
>   $$F(u)\le F(u+\epsilon v)$$
>   If we define $g(\epsilon):=F(u+\epsilon v)$ this function is minimized when $\epsilon=0$, so that...*

And then follows the part I don't quite get,

> *... $\frac{dg}{d\epsilon}|_{\epsilon=0}=0$"*

How is it we can say that the entire expression, once evaluated at $\epsilon=0$, equals zero?

What I get when working it out by hand is,

$$\frac{dg}{d\epsilon}=\epsilon(v',v')+(u',u')-(f,v)$$
$$\implies\frac{dg}{d\epsilon}|_{\epsilon=0}=(u',u')-(f,v)$$

How do we know that this is equal to zero?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to find extreme points of the energy functional $F$ (i.e. trying to find the function that minimizes total energy). Opening up your condition gives
$$
0=\frac{\mathrm{d}g}{\mathrm{d}\epsilon}\Big|_{\epsilon=0} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\epsilon}F(u+\epsilon v)\Big|_{\epsilon=0} =: DF(u)v,
$$
where on the right hand side you have the definition of Gâteaux differential of $F$ at $u$ into direction $v$ (generalization of the directional derivative to Banach spaces)—here denoted by $DF(u)v$ emphasizing that $DF(u)$ defines an operator acting on $v$. Now analogously to real valued functions, you want your extreme point $u$ to satisfy $DF(u)v=0$ for every direction $v$.

Since your energy is of such form, you can actually show that the resulting $u$ corresponds to the global minimum.